# renderPartial after a request with dropDownList

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

First, note that I have noticed that the common Yii widgets that have paginators, can go to any page without reloading the page, but just requesting it via AJAX and then changing the content of the already loaded page. Such behavior will completely satisfy my current needs.

I have a simple `dropDownList` in one of my views. What I'm trying to do is to change the content of the page **without** reloading the page, just like Yii's widgets.

Is that possible? How?

I tried doing something like this in my controller:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
    $this->renderPartial(.....);
}
```

and this in my `dropDownList`:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('usage', 'cg', array(
        'd'=>'Daily',
        'm'=>'Monthly'
    ), array(
        'submit'=>array('admin/user', 'id'=>$user->iduser),
        'params'=>array('cg'=>'js:$(this).val()'),
        'options'=>array(
            Yii::app()->session['cg']=>array(
                'selected'=>true
            )
        )
    ));
?>
```

but the `dropDownList` keeps reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following to reload content of div depending upon the selected value of dropDownList.Might be helpful to you.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('usage','cg',array('d'=>'Daily','m'=>'Monthly'),array('ajax'=>array(
        'type'=>'POST', //request type
        'url'=>$this->createUrl('controller/loadContent'), //url to call.
        'update'=>'#div_id',//div to update
        'data'=>array('cg'=>'js:this.value') 
        ))); 


public function actionLoadContent()
{
   ..........
   ..........
   $this->renderPartial('_ajaxContent', $data, false, true);
}
```

Comment: That works great in 99.9% of cases, but mine is a little bit special. I'm updating the entire content of the page, which means all `.js` files are reloaded. How can I make the `update` option act just like Yii's widgets? If I set `update=>'document'`, some javascript libs crash because they are being loaded twice (once when the page is loaded and once when I select something in the dropDownList).

Comment: @b3wii Should I put this before or after calling `render()` ?

Comment: It depends on how your script files are loaded. For example you can use Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery.ui.js'=>false,); to disable rendering of jquery ui before using renderPartial.

Comment: @b3wii Ok, the problem seems to be elsewhere, I'm opening another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491578/highcharts-yii-and-body-content-reloading