# Highcharts, Yii and body content reloading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, highcharts

I have a view that renders some data in a `CListView` and a Highcharts graphic.

Please note that the pager of the `CListView` works the following way: it requests the "new page" to the server, the servers renders the entire content of the page and sends it to the `CListView`. The body is then replaced with the content that is being sent, with something like this: `$('body').html(rendered_html_response)`.

I also have a `dropDownList` that imitates this behavior. This is the code:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('usage', 'cg', array(
        'd'=>'Daily',
        'm'=>'Monhly'
    ), array(
        'ajax'=>array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>$this->createUrl('admin/user', array(
                'id'=>$user->id)
            ),
            'update'=>'body',
            'data'=>array('cg'=>'js:$(this).val()'), 
            'options'=>array(
                Yii::app()->session['cg']=>array(
                    'selected'=>true
                )
            )
        )
    ));
?>
```

Anyways, there is a problem. When I use the `CListView`, everything works fine (as in: the page's content is refreshed without the page being reloaded, the charts and the data are rendered correctly, etc...), but when I select something using the `dropDownList`, the server renders the reply, sends it to the client, the client starts replacing the content of `body`, but then I get this error: `http://www.highcharts.com/errors/16`.

I tried disabling `highcharts.src.js` this way:

```
public function beforeAction(){
    if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
        Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['highcharts.src.js'] = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but then I get the typical `undefined` javascript error (means that *something* is trying to use `Highcharts`, which is not defined).

Where is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit your Post and add all relevant code snippets like (main view, partial view and controller)

Answer (score 0):

```
//init
$('#container').highcharts({});
//select onchange
$('#container').highcharts().destroy();
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. I tried placing that code in multiple places. Before/after sending the request, before/after replacing the DOM and right before inserting the new chart.

Answer (score 0):

As following the error link says

> Highcharts already defined in the page
>
> This error happens the second time Highcharts or Highstock is loaded in the same page, so the Highcharts namespace is already defined. Keep in mind that the Highcharts.Chart constructor and all features of Highcharts are included in Highstock, so if you are running Chart and StockChart in combination, you only need to load the highstock.js file.

You are loading the highcharts javascript twice. You can try

a) enabling highcharts on the first load and then disabling it on the next e.g perhaps checking if ajax

b) use custom javascript to check whether highcharts has been loaded as in [this blog post](http://www.eirikhoem.net/blog/2011/08/29/yii-framework-preventing-duplicate-jscss-includes-for-ajax-requests/)

c) use the [NLSClientScript extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript/) that handles js and css loading for you

I suggest you use the last one. I was bitten by this problem a couple of times until I discovered it. It eliminates the need to single out each javascript function/file.

**EDIT**

Instead of editing the listview js, you can edit your code to use the same `update` function:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('usage', 'cg', array(
        'd'=>'Daily',
        'm'=>'Monhly'
    ), array(
        'onChange'=>'$.fn.yiiListView.update("your-list-id", {
            data: {"usage":$(this).val()},
            type: "POST"
        });'
    ));
?>
```

Comment: AFAIK I'm doing your `a` suggestion in my `beforeAction` code, right? That doesn't work either.

Comment: No. Your `beforeAction` prevents highcharts from loading in the first place hence the error.

Comment: No, my `beforeAction` prevents the loading of the script *only* if it's an AJAX request (hence, the second time).

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I hadn't read your comment completely. It could be because you are replacing `body`. `CListView` replaces only it's html element and not body.

Comment: Again, AFAIK `CListView` requests the entire body and replaces the entire body. At least that's what I see in the request response.

Comment: The update function does request the entire body. It however only replaces a small section as the [listview javascript file](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/zii/widgets/assets/listview/jquery.yiilistview.js#L123) reads `$(id).replaceWith($(id,'<div>'+data+'</div>'));`

Comment: Ah, true. How can I catch the server's response? I should delete the `update` line and add a handler, but I'm not sure what is the event's name. Where can I have a list of events supported in this widget?